# Integral using gamma function $\int_0^1 x^a(1-x)^b dx = \frac{\Gamma(1 + a) \Gamma(1 + b)}{\Gamma(2 + a + b)} $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Does anyone knows how to show

$$\int_0^1 x^a(1-x)^b dx = \frac{\Gamma(a+b-2)}{\Gamma( a -1)\Gamma(b-1)} $$
for $a,b \gt -1?$

Also why it doesn't work for $a$ or $b\lt -1$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function

Comment: It is actually true as long as $a$, $b >-1$ (in fact $\Re a$, $\Re b>-1$).

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't see how it helps

Comment: @SAJ How does it help? It gives you the proof of your identity in the title of your question.

Comment: Google "Beta function".

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone knows how to show...

I cannot, because it is wrong. Using the definition of [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) you have that

$$\int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$

that in your case gives the following result

$$\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+2)}$$

---

to realize that your result does not make sense, set $a,b=1$ and you get

$$\int_0^1 dx=\frac{\Gamma(-2)}{\Gamma(-1)\Gamma(-1)}$$

??????

While using my result you get

$$\int_0^1 dx=\frac{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(2)}=\frac{0!\cdot0!}{1!}=1$$

Comment: The title shows the original question (before the OP edited it) which was correct.

Comment: @Gary ops, sorry, I didn't read the whole title...my fault, anyway my answer is still valid. Thanks for your comment

Comment: In some way, you are right. I don't know why the OP edited the question into a non-sense.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you wrote in the question is incorrect. In the title you have the correct one. To prove it, let's consider
\begin{align} \Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1) &= \int_0^\infty t^a e^{-t}dt \int_0^\infty s^b e^{-s}ds = \\
&= \int_0^\infty  \Big( \int_0^\infty t^a s^b e^{-t-s}ds \Big) dt = \\
&= \int_0^\infty \Big( \int_t^\infty t^a (u-t)^b e^{-u}du \Big) dt = \\
&= \int_0^\infty \Big( \int_0^u t^a (u-t)^b e^{-u} dt \Big) du =  \\
&= \int_0^\infty \Big( \int_0^1 (ux)^a (u-ux)^b udx \Big) e^{-u}  du = \\
&= \int_0^\infty \Big( \int_0^1 x^a (1-x)^b dx \Big) u^{a+b+1} e^{-u} du = \\
&= \int_0^\infty u^{a+b+1} e^{-u} du \int_0^1 x^a (1-x)^b dx = \\
&= \Gamma(a+b+2)\int_0^1 x^a (1-x)^b dx  \end{align}

It doesn't work if $a<-1$ or $b<-1$ because this integral are not converegnt for such values of $a$ and $b$.